# Spring RestTemplate timeout configuration not working

Tags: java, spring, resttemplate, sap-commerce-cloud

I have a hybris application which uses rest template to make a call to the restful API and consumes a json response. I am observing that when the application hits the apis multiple times during the load ,the response times from these api's increase significantly.I have set the timeouts as 15 seconds ,but those timeouts do not get applied.The connection still remains open and it keeps waiting for the response for as high as 5 minutes.I do not see any exception the logs for such long requsts and it does not time out as well.

Below is the code that i am using to set the time out.Is there anything which i am missing to set to enable the time outs to be applied.

```
public <E, T> E processService(String Url, final T serviceReq,
            final Class<E> serviceResponse, final HttpMethod 
httpMethod, final MediaType contentType,
            final Map<String, String> queryParams, final 
Map<String, String> header,
            final Map<String, String> pathVariables) throws 
Exception {
        RestTemplate restTemplate = getRestTemplate();
        setTimeoutProperties(restTemplate);
       <business logic to fire request and process response>}

private RestTemplate getRestTemplate() {
    if (LOG.isDebugEnabled()) {

getRestTemplate().setInterceptors(Collections.singletonList(new 
RequestResponseLoggingInterceptor()));
    }
    return getRestTemplate();
}



private void setTimeoutProperties(RestTemplate template) {
    final int readTimeout = configurationService.getConfiguration().getInteger("client.readtimeout",
            5000);
    final int connectTimeout = configurationService.getConfiguration()
            .getInteger("client.connectiontimeout", 5000);
    if (template.getRequestFactory() instanceof HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory) {
        HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory httpRequestFactory = (HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory) template
                .getRequestFactory();
        httpRequestFactory.setConnectTimeout(connectTimeout);
        httpRequestFactory.setReadTimeout(readTimeout);     
        httpRequestFactory.setConnectionRequestTimeout(connectTimeout);

    } 
}
```

Comment: Is it even making the call? Is it running out of memory? Why does getRestTemplate() call itself?

Comment: Since the number of calls made to the API's is approximately 4000/min on a busy day in production env , i an suspecting that the connection pool is unable to handle this kinda of load and the request gets stuck trying to get the connection from the pool itself.Are there any recommended connection pool settings for such large number of requests.Also getRestTemplate() call is made to intercept to log the request going out for troubleshooting purposes.